# (WARN) Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have `"jest": "^29.2.1"`. My unit tests output errors like this:

```
ts-jest[ts-jest-transformer] (WARN) Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated. Please do
transform: {
    <transform_regex>: ['ts-jest', { /* ts-jest config goes here in Jest */ }],
},
ts-jest[backports] (WARN) "[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.tsConfig" is deprecated, use "[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.tsconfig" instead.
ts-jest[backports] (WARN) Your Jest configuration is outdated. Use the CLI to help migrating it: ts-jest config:migrate <config-file>.
```

My `jest.config.ts` is the following:

```
const config = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  verbose: true,
  globalSetup: './globalSetup.ts',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: 'http://localhost/',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest', {}],
    '^.+\\.ts?$': ['ts-jest', {}],
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/**/(*.)test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      babel: true,
      tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
}

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 40):

I've had a similar warning and the solution was already in the answer (but I hand't understood the first time) You have to move the content of `globals` into the `transform` keys.
The file must look like this:

```js
const config = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  verbose: true,
  globalSetup: './globalSetup.ts',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: 'http://localhost/',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest', {//the content you'd placed at "global"
      babel: true,
      tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json',
    }]
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/**/(*.)test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ]
}

module.exports = config
```

Also, it seems you can skip the second transform (the regex expression loos the same) the first one applies both to `.ts` and `.tsx` files and the second to `.t` and `.ts`

Comment: please, remove anything from my side as it was done by mistake

Comment: "tsConfig" is deprecated, use "tsconfig" instead.

Comment: I have done this, yet Jest still gives me the same warning `Define \`ts-jest\` config under \`globals\` is deprecated.`. There are 0 results when I search my codebase for `globals`. Why is it still warning me about this? Any pointers?

Comment: @DanielSaner did you figure out what caused this, I'm having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by removing the whole property `globals`. As a result the present state of `const config.ts` is the following:

```js
const config = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  verbose: true,
  globalSetup: './globalSetup.ts',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: 'http://localhost/',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.{ts|tsx}?$': ['ts-jest', {
      babel: true,
      tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json',
    }],

  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/**/(*.)test.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
}

module.exports = config
```